# Avoid useless edit about byte count

Tags: discussion, editing, reviewing

I like having my byte count history this way:

210 <s>212 219</s>

But there is some user that keep [editing my answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/28738) to put it this way:

<s>212 219</s> 210

Citing @PhiNotPi "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible."

What can I do to avoid these kind of edits, apart from posting my complaint here?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you prefer it?

Comment: @ThomasKwa because the first number is the important one, all the rest is just there as a remainder

Comment: Considering that most users now put `bytes` at the end of the header, it makes the most sense to have the final score at the end before the word.

Answer (score 16):

> What can I do to avoid these kind of edits, apart from posting my complaint here?

Put them in the right order to begin with. ;)

I'm kidding, of course - you're free to put them in any order you like. If someone does that once or twice, I wouldn't worry about it and just reject/rollback the edit. If they insist on it, and either start a rollback war or keep doing it over many of your posts, flag one of them with a custom message to explain the issue and we (the mods) will have a look at it.

Comment: Am I imagining things, or does the leaderboard snippet require that the current count should be last?

Comment: @Neil It ignores numbers that are struck out, but if there are multiple numbers *not* inside `<s></s>` e.g. because of something like `23 + 21 = 44 bytes` then the last such number is used.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: On the PPCG design userscript it's leaderboard does tend to be confused when the byte count isn't last

Comment: @Downgoat time to improve the user script ;)